# Cloudformation complex parameters file

Tags: amazon-web-services, config, aws-cloudformation

How to set complex parameters json file with group names that I can later refer in stack file as !Ref DBUser?

Here is example of my parameters.json file:

```
[
{
  "ParameterKey": "DBName",
  "ParameterValue": {
     "Default": "test",
     "Description": "The database name",
     "Type": "String",
     "MinLength": "1",
     "MaxLength": "64",
     "AllowedPattern": "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*",
     "ConstraintDescription": "must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters."
  }
},
{
  "ParameterKey": "DBUser",
  "ParameterValue" : {
     "NoEcho": "true",
     "Default": "test",
     "Description": "The database admin account username",
     "Type": "String",
     "MinLength": "1",
     "MaxLength": "16",
     "AllowedPattern": "[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*",
     "ConstraintDescription": "must begin with a letter and contain only alphanumeric characters."
  }
}
```

]

I get errors like this:

```
Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in Parameters[0]: "Label", must be one of: ParameterKey, ParameterValue, UsePreviousValue, ResolvedValue
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are getting two different files confused.

The **CloudFormation template** is used to define parameters, resources and outputs. The `parameters` section looks like:

```
"VPCCIDR": {
  "Description": "CIDR Block for VPC",
  "Type": "String",
  "Default": "10.0.0.0/16",
  "AllowedValues": [
    "10.0.0.0/16"
  ]
},
```

The definition includes the type of parameter, default value, etc.

Then there is the **parameter file** that can be used to pass-in values for the parameters defined in the template. This file does *not* define the parameters themselves — rather, it provides a list of values for the parameters rather than having to specify them on the command-line.

It looks like:

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "string",
    "ParameterValue": "string",
    "UsePreviousValue": true|false,
    "ResolvedValue": "string"
  }
  ...
]
```

From your question, I think you should be using the **first type of file**, which defines all the resources that should be deployed in the CloudFormation stack, whereas your code (above) is attempting to put these fields into format for the **second type of file**.

See: [Sample Templates - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-sample-templates.html)